# Can I set the SSLInsecureRenegotiation Directive with SetEnvIf?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, openssl

We're running Apache 2.2.22 with OpenSSL 0.98, one of our Citrix NetScaler Hosts cannot send a client certificate after handshaking SSL as we have to set SSLInsecureRenegotiation off as a security standard.

Is there anyway to dynamically set this directive based on Remote_Addr?  I have tried so many settings but as designed I guess, there doesn't seem to be a way of selectively allowing SSLInsecureRenegotiation for one user agent or IP?

We've already patched to latest NetScaler 10, but after the SSL initial handshake a renegotiation request is sent back from Apache to the NetScaler because as a client cert is required for a LocationMatch, this is never responded to leading Apache to terminate session. - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746#section-3.5 . We're told by Citrix that downstream rules are normally on a "trusted" network, and not supported using the client method, is it possible to differentiate between requests and how the SSLInsecureRenegotiation directive is called by host identity of some sort or IP?

Some comments from other forum -

I don't believe it can be set anywhere lower than virtual server level, which is why I'm thinking it needs to be addressed at the load-balancer, (despite what Citrix might say). They seem to have quite a few different values that TLS Renegotiation that can be set, including disabling renegotiation support between client and server altogether. Maybe posting this question over on serverfault will help? – mahnsc 14 hours ago

Hi, problem is more that SSL offload is designed to operate in front of web servers, not clients end but unfortunately our project went ahead regardless. Citrix have not fully implemented RFC 5746 extension to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks out the backend as they consider the backend behind the Netscaler (Logical in this reversed context) a trusted channel, with a 3rd party hosting Apache with the strict security rules for all traffic. I could probably convince them to set a special case for our host, but can't find a way of setting the directive in-session. – ev4nsj 14 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply an update to your NetScaler hosts as described in [Citrix security bulletin CTX123359](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX123359).

[Appliance firmware version 8.1, build 68.7 or later, and version 9.1, build 99.8 or later](https://www.citrix.com/English/ss/downloads/results.asp?productID=21679).

Comment: Many thanks, we've patched to latest NetScaler 10 but can't send back that the "renegotiation_info" extension is present, this aborts the session.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your reply, Citrix have basically said that when netscaler acts as a client, it never sends the extension as the backend zone is assumed to be on a secure network,it's not something that they have enabled or support running in client mode.

- IE/Latest Browser
- HTTP to NetScaler alias
- HTTP-HTTPS rewrite + client certificate to Apache..

I believe the NetScaler doesn't reply as being able to securely renegotiate and the session is terminated.   

Is it possible to set this directive off (or others) if the client comes from a particular host identity?